# Why does O.W.C.A. never recruit humans as agents?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

First thing I thought is that humans must be paid for their work, which is not something that O.W.C.A. wants. But then I realized that Carl is human and he is not paid for his work. Don't forget that Carl is actually very useful!

So, why not recruit more humans that are very useful and don't need to be paid just like Carl?
You might say that not many humans would want to work for free, but there are definitely people like Carl who would.
Is it because non-human agents are better suited for their tasks? If so, then in what way?

I even remember an episode where a flower was recruited as an agent and flowers are not even animals.

Comment: [This Fandom wiki entry](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Organization_Without_a_Cool_Acronym) says even Major Monogram doesn't know why all the agents are animals.

Comment: Note that the Canadian Organization Without a Cool Acronym (C.O.W.C.A) has at least 1 human agent, and that the Super Secret Spy Network (SSSN), which is under O.W.C.A. jurisdiction, has several human agents.

Comment: That's not exactly true: Doofenshmirtz was briefly an agent (until he was fired for making bad puns at ducks) and in the "Act your age" episode, set 10 years in the future, Doof's daughter gets accepted into O.W.C.A.

Comment: Huh, wonder if someone out there knew "owca" means "sheep" in Polish... ech pewnie nie.

Comment: Doof doesn't count - he got in because legally he's an ocelot

Comment: Here's a quote from "The O.W.C.A files, regarding Doof's status: "
"And, Doofenshmirtz, you're lucky you're legally considered an ocelot, or you wouldn't be here at all!"